# Get the query string on the called javascript file

Tags: javascript, file, url, query-string

Is it possible to get the query parameters with javascript on the called javascript file like this:

```
// in html
<script src="/file.js?query=string"></script>

// in file.js
console.log(this.location.query)
```

Is this possible somehow, or I have to use the server?

Comment: You'd have to use the server AFAIK, but why not just set the appropriate JS variables in a separate `<script>` block before calling the JS file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible, because the script file has no representation within the global javascript scope. You can only find its element inside the DOM as shown by haitaka, but this is a highly non-standard and certainly not recommended way to pass parameters to script.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right, but I wanted to ask it, because who knows :)

Answer (score 16):

You may append id attribute to script tag like this:

```
<script src="/file.js?query=string" id="query"></script>
```

and then call it:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("query").src.split("query=")[1]);
```

A small working sample code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="aaa.js?query=abcd" id="query"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Here is the code inside of aaa.js:

```
window.onload=function(){
    alert(document.getElementById("query").src.split("query=")[1]);
}
```

Comment: how can I call this from inside the script?

Answer (score 15):

I could get src with below code. So I think that you can parse queryString.

```
document.currentScript.src
```

Comment: Good answer, but work noting that this isnt supported by IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript

Comment: Haha nice...We shouldn't worry about IE anymore 

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but I thought you wouldn't mind (yet another) two more cents...

If you are NOT adding an id to the script element, James Smith has [a snippet that does not require an id attribute](http://loopj.com/2010/06/12/simple-way-to-extract-get-params-from-a-javascript-script-tag/). And that id-less characteristic is huge, because your script file does NOT need to couple with an ID in the caller's side.

```js
// Extract "GET" parameters from a JS include querystring
function getParams(script_name) {
  // Find all script tags
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
  
  // Look through them trying to find ourselves
  for(var i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
    if(scripts[i].src.indexOf("/" + script_name) > -1) {
      // Get an array of key=value strings of params
      var pa = scripts[i].src.split("?").pop().split("&");

      // Split each key=value into array, the construct js object
      var p = {};
      for(var j=0; j<pa.length; j++) {
        var kv = pa[j].split("=");
        p[kv[0]] = kv[1];
      }
      return p;
    }
  }
  
  // No scripts match
  return {};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `document.currentScript.src` (only at the appropriate time) and `URLSearchParams` to extract the query string from the called JavasScript file.

Example:

In your HTML:

```
<script src="querystring.js?foo=bar&foo=bar2"></script>
```

In your JavaScript file:

```
/**
 * When this is being run, the document's last element will be this very script.
 * Explanations on http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html
 */
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var index = scripts.length - 1;
var myScript = scripts[index];
  // document.currentScript.src will be this file's URL, including its query string.
  // e.g. file:///mytests/querystring.js?foo=script

/**
 * Now just turn the query string (if any) into a URLSearchParams
to let us easily check values.
 */
var querystring = document.currentScript.src.substring( document.currentScript.src.indexOf("?") );
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams( querystring );

console.log( urlParams.getAll('foo') ); // Array [ "bar", "bar2" ]
```

Keep in mind:

- This might not work when the script is included via async.
- get or getAll?

  - `urlParams.get` will only return the first value (as a string)
  - `urlParams.getAll` will return an array (of size 1 if just one value is provided.)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I thought I'd throw in my two cents...

If you are already adding an id to the script element, why not add a custom attribute as well:

```
<script src="/file.js" id="query" value="string"></script>
```

Then you can grab the value using getAttribute:

```
document.getElementById('query').getAttribute('value');
```

Answer (score 0):

When an HTML file uses a **Script** tag with a **src** attribute that includes a query string to load a JavaScript program, you cannot use location.search to retrieve the query string, because location does not contain the URL (as it does with the **href** attribute). The URL can be obtained using "new URL(here.src).search", where "here" is a string you use in the Script **id** attribute.

Thus, one solution (from another answer elsewhere, that does not decode the arguments) is

```
var queryDict = {};
new URL(here.src).search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {queryDict[item.split("=")[0]] = item.split("=")[1]})
```

After running this code, queryDict is an object containing the argument property/value pairs.

Answer (score -3):

Try like this to get the value of query using javascript

```
alert(window.location.href.split["?"][1].split["="][1]);
```

Comment: this tries to find the query in the global document not in the javascript file as I see.