# Get parameter from javascript url

Tags: javascript

how I can get parameters from my script url? I found examples where was parameters from website url but it's not what i really looking for. I'm running one script from another and I send request like `/script.js?name=example` and I don't have idea how I can get access to name in `script.js`.

Greetings.

Comment: See [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/)

Comment: it'll work for example.com/?name=example but i sending parameter to script name (example.com/script.js?name=example). But I was trying, returned false ;)

Comment: Script has no access to it.

Comment: I guess you are not using Node, right?

Comment: pure javascript and symfony

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716612/how-do-i-get-query-string-value-from-script-path

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223884/get-the-query-string-on-the-called-javascript-file